# Where can I go to dance salsa in Sorrento, Italy, in September?

Tags: italy, sorrento, dance

I’ll be on holiday in Sorrento for 5 nights in mid September, starting on Sunday 17th. Are there any latino bars or venues in and around the city centre where I can dance Cuban salsa (not LA-style), or maybe bachata?

I’ve tried searching online but couldn’t find anything.

Note: I don’t have an Instagram or FB profile and I’m not interested in venues/organisations that only offer classes.

Comment: FYI I was pointing out the places that offer classes only because they are the places where you are guaranteed to find people who have intimate knowledge about the local venues.

Answer (score 7):

While there's always the possibility of someone on here knowing, I suggest that you need to chase down some local knowledge.  A quick google showed me that there is a Sorrento Salsa group on instagram.

I also saw "Salsa Cubana Napoli" has both instagram and facebook profiles. (but I don't have an instagram account, and you need to join that FB group to see it).  But their FB profile does mention rueda, so that's in the general ballpark of style.

And I also found [this](https://www.saidovesiballa.com/dovequando/salsa-cubana-sorrento/) website that seems to list events and clubs in the area.

I have no idea about what style of music they play in these venues (the last time I danced Salsa in Italy was in Taranto in the early 2000's), but I saw a tip on a reddit post that I'd agree with - you're likely to get better information from the dance community than the travel community.